# Number of unique visitors on a website hosted on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, statistics, analytics, visitors

Is there any kind of analytics tool on AWS? I might be missing something here, but I couldn't find an AWS tool to monitor my website's traffic.

To be more precise, I want to know the number of unique visitors, and maybe some statistics about the countries, time, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't an AWS tool. [Google Analytics](https://www.google.com/analytics/) is a good choice for this.